# How to resize button after setBackgroundResource in android

Tags: android, image-resizing

Please help me to resize one button on android code.

I have one button and after calling `setBackgroundResource` for this, I can't resize it.

The image 480x320 px,I want re-size it to 150x150 px for button.

```
View rowView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu, null);     
Button img;
img = (Button)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgitems);
img.setBackgroundResource(imageId[position]);  //( my image is 480x320)
img.setWidth(150); // not work
img.setHeight(150); // not work
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
button.getLayoutParams().width = 150;

button.getLayoutParams().height = 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
img.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
```

Hope it helps.